# How should I implement login with secure authentication?

Tags: security, authentication

I hear of all these various things such as https, ssl/tls, srp, md5, sha, bcrypt, and so on. Which of these do I need exactly and which do I not need? And in what form should the password be stored in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For normal web, it is implement using http, that is the communication between 
the client (often browsers) and the server is in plaintext. To ensure the data
is encrypted, the ssl is applied on http and thus the acronym https. Now to store
the user password in database, you can probably applied one way hash algorithm
such as md5 and sha. Thus, when you submit the password over the network, the 
password is encrypted in the https communication and thus it is safe from the
eavedropper. The server should apply the crytographic hash function against the
password submit by the user and match against the encrypted password stored 
inside the database.

Comment: So what is secure remote password protocol (srp) useful for if https already exists to allow the password to be sent encrypted?

Comment: @user782220 For one, that srp and https are applied in different field? Read these two links to get an idea what they are and which one you should choose when solving your problem.
[link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol#Real_world_implementations)
[link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Main_idea)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, passwords stored in DataBase in such way:
md5($pass.$sercetkey);

Because simple md5 with no additional key can be matched brute force

Comment: MD5 is deprecated. There's no reason to use it in new applications. SHA-256 is a better idea.